# If slope becomes infinite, why do we still call the polynomial a function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

I asked a question regarding 
[why parabolas' arms become parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916720/why-do-parabolas-arms-eventually-become-parallel) . I received many good answer. But sometime back a question popped up in my mind- **If slope of the graph of a quadratic polynomial becomes infinite as $x \to \infty$ then why do we still call it a function?**

One of the main aspect of a function is that for every argument, it returns only **one** value. But as $x \to \infty$ the the arms of parabola become parallel i.e. it returns many values for one value of $x$. So, why do we still call it a function?

Comment: $\infty\notin \mathbb R$

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns many values for one value of $x$"? For which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you get many values?

Comment: The arms "approach" a state of being parallel but are never ACTUALLY parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But as $x \to \infty$ the the arms of parabola become parallel i.e. it returns many values for one value of $x$.

This is not quite right. Consider the parabola $f(x)=x^2$. Although the slope $f'(x)=2x$ goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, that does not mean that $f$ returns many values for a given value of $x$. For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2$.

However, $\infty\not\in\mathbb{R}$. You cannot take $f(\infty)$.